# How much of what we know about ancient philosophers comes from oral literature?

Tags: middle-ages, literature, classical-antiquity, philosophy, history-of-ideas

Have any orally-transmitted myths survived​ throughout the centuries in such a form that we could identify any of the ancient philosophers of Classical Greece and Rome in them? I'm interested in finding out how much could their philosophies actually affect thinking of people in the Middle Ages.

Comment: "Antic philosophers"?  Do you perhaps mean antique philosophers, in the sense of Classical Greek & Roman philosopy?  Antic philosophers conjures up all sorts of interesting mental images :-)

Comment: "orally-transmitted myths" about "ancient philosophers" ? We have *text* from ancient Greece philosophy that influenced MA: Plato, Aristotle, pseudo-Platonic and pseudo-Aristotle.

Comment: But also some "forgeries", like the [Corpus Hermeticum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermeticism).

Comment: Don't the Old and New Testaments qualify?

Comment: There are also the *gathas* of Zarathrustha, the *Upanishads* in India and given how important Homer was to the Greek cultural life, then Homer.

Comment: Can you provide a working definition of "oral literature" in your question so that people reading your question do not make the assumption that they are dealing with an oxymoron?  It's not that common of a term.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy Sorry, I only meant the philosophers of the Ancient Greece and Rome,edited the question.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I only meant the Greek and Roman philosophers, I edited the question

Comment: @Probably: in that case, doesn't Socrates apply? He never wrote a thing, but was deeply influential. Also, the question could use some rewording, as it really isn't so clear what you're after.

Comment: When I read Diogenes Laertius's *Lives of the Philosophers* I got the impression that a great deal of his knowledge was derived from unreliable oral tradition, and that tidbits about his subjects' idiosyncrasies were much more like survive than technical expositions of what his subjects actually thought.

Comment: @Probably I gave, and just expanded today, an answer below. Please let me know if this is/isn't the direction you were hoping to take your inquiry.

Comment: I too am actually a little confused at what you mean by "oral literature". If you mean literature that was eventually produced about a person based upon the oral transmission of things claimed about a person and what they said, then I think I have understood your intent.

Comment: @SeligkeitIstInGott No, I meant [oral literature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oral_literature).

Comment: @Probably Hmm, okay, that terminology is new to me. Very interesting. Discussions of the "orality of literature/texts" are common in academic discussions about ancient works especially when trying to reconstruct a theoretical pre-textual oral form (often in conjunction with the concept of 'Sitz im Leben') that contributed to the form of the written text, and so my first assumption upon seeing "oral literature" was something closer to that. But thank you for the clarification. I'll have to keep that terminology in mind in future reading.

Comment: I'll be glad for any other views, don't think either answer answers my question.

Comment: @Probably I truly hope a subject matter expert on the ancient world and Medieval times comes by and can answer that question about oral tradition or legends that survived about the philosophers specifically. If I encounter anything by way of research in the future I'll update my answer. However, perhaps the best I can do for now is to reference you to another forum. If you are on Facebook there is an excellent group called "Nerdy Classics Majors" who live and breathe to answer questions about the classics and many are versed in Attic Greek and Latin. You might get some helpful responses there.

Comment: You may also want to go out on a limb in your OP and give an example of what you hope or expect to find, like "I wonder if Medieval royal court poets like Chaucer slightly embellished the Greek philosophers to resonate with English imperial themes of the period." Honestly, I tried my own suggestion of hitting journals & search engines just now and am finding very little on such a broad topic. I noticed that "humanism" kept popping up as well as art & theater (oral) as preservers of themes from antiquity. Tell me if this helps at all (3rd pg citation of Walter Ong): https://tinyurl.com/y9lbhjms

Answer (score 5):

### I think you want to start by reading a little Dante.

> Here I saw Socrates and Plato, who in front of the others stands
>   nearest to him; Democritus, who ascribes the world to chance;
>   Diogenes, Anaxagoras, and Thales; Empedocles, Heraclitus and Zeno; and
>   I saw the good collector of the qualities, Dioscorides, I mean, and I
>   saw Orpheus, Tully and Linus and moral Seneca; Euclid the geometer,
>   and Ptolemy, Hippocrates, Avicenna, and Galen, and Averrhoes, who made
>   the great comment.
>    - Inferno, Canto IV.

Dante clearly expected his audience to know who these people were.  Which tells you that as of about 1300AD, people had some smattering of knowledge - and not just the educated monks, but the general audience that Dante was writing in vulgar *Italian* for.  Dante assumed the burghers knew not just of the names of the philosophers, but a bit about their most influential ideas.

We can only guess how much of this written literature was influenced by the oral literature of the era, or how it seeped into the oral culture that followed.  But Dante wrote in verse for a reason - it was written to be read aloud and perhaps to be memorized and passed on orally.  It seems hard to imagine that Dante's works were isolated from the oral literature of the time.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't hand waving the context of the times away? Dante lived in a period where Europeans were soaking antiquity's literary classics out of Sicily and Cordoba. And the few literate elites and monks of the time would have been familiar with these names, if only because there wasn't that much else to read. Methinks there's very little chance your average villein would be familiar with these names.

Comment: @DenisdeBernardy: Not a *typical* villain agreed; but an *upwardly mobile* villain and the burgeoning *middle class* that would soon fill the Globe Theatre in London to enjoy Shakespeare & Marlowe most certainly yes.

Comment: If Dante has been writing just for monks, would he have written in Tuscan?

Answer (score 4):

**Edit:** Now that the OP question has been reworded for clarity I will tip my hat to **pokep** as being closer to answering the intent of the inquiry. It was not clear to me originally where orality and myth came into the picture with literature in the question. Nonetheless, I'll leave my answer here in case it helps anyone.

I'm afraid you're probably not going to get away without doing some research of your own on this, but perhaps some pointers could help. Firstly, since you give such generous leeway with respect to the period of time under consideration (from the lifetimes of the ancient philosophers up to the Middle Ages) I feel at liberty to jump around a little bit.

Firstly, from your title alone (**"How much of what we know about ancient philosophers comes from oral literature?"**) I immediately thought of the matter of ***Socrates*** and what we know of him and how we know it. We have [no writings from Socrates himself](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Socrates), and are dependent largely on Plato for telling us what Socrates taught. That in itself presents us with a *dependence on orally transmitted details about a person* of a **truly ancient provenance** (almost from the get go). So oral transmission of knowledge about a person need not be something long after the fact and also need not be inherently suspect or inaccurate.

It seems ironic, however, that the historicity (existence) of Socrates as a person and the essential content of his teachings are rarely called into question, despite us having no written records from him personally; yet all the while some "mythicists" call into the question the historicity of Jesus of Nazareth and his essential teachings (which also relies on sources that provide orally transmitted details from early witnesses who knew him personally, rather than from any direct writings by him). The same can be said for Siddhārtha Gautama (Buddha). There are good reasons to regard them all as real historical figures whose teachings have reached us accurately by their ancient witness-bearers who wrote them down.

To take one ancient example from the Hellenistic world, the fields of New Testament studies (in the case of Jesus and early Christian history - as Koine Greek speakers and/or writers), Orality, Textual Transmission, and Historiography are all even disciplinarily related - resting upon the same historiographical foundations and inquiries - to this same question you raise about *orally transmitted details of ancient figures and their teachings*. The questions and methodological principles for analyzing such orally transmitted accounts (especially in such a largely oral culture) applies equally to New Testament studies and the study of any Greek or Roman literature or historical sources in general. So studying orally transmitted details about Greek Philosophers will involve the same interdisciplinary considerations to determine historicity.

The field of study on those topics of orality and historiographical textual studies is vast, and I have seen much discussion of it in NT studies (which is why I mention it), and no doubt broader studies on Greek literature and historical sources may be found which would apply to Greek Philosophers. I would just recommend spending time on a search engine, journal aggregate sites like [JSTOR](https://www.jstor.org/) (which now provides some limited free access), or book catalogues such as [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/) searching for keywords like "**Orality**" and "**Greek literature**" or "**Greek History**" (Substitute "Hellenistic" for "Greek" where appropriate) and start where you can.

Further, aside from such foundational matters, if you wish to find a good compendium of ancient knowledge about all manner of elements of Greek and Roman culture and language as understood by a later civilization, **the Byzantines**, then I recommend doing some research on [**the Suda**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suda). This may help *bridge the gap from classical times to the Middle Ages*, as you discussed. As Wikipedia states the **Suda** "*is a large 10th-century Byzantine encyclopedia of the ancient Mediterranean world*". It is part lexicon and part encyclopedia but presents a broad understanding of knowledge of the classical world, and may provide you some clues for what you endeavor to research. I often see it cited in academic literature when someone is debating the meaning of Greek words in classical literature (often as applied to exegetical analysis of Greek texts), but it also provides some details of ancient knowledge and facts as understood at the time. As the Wikipedia article states:

> The articles on literary history are especially valuable. These entries supply details and quotations from authors whose works are otherwise lost.[4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suda)

One Byzantine churchman and scholar who wrote widely on Greek classics and also made reference to the Suda was [Eustathius of Thessalonica](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eustathius_of_Thessalonica). In the *Encyclopedia of Ancient Greece* by **Nigel Wilson** (pg. 60) it says:

> Noted Classical scholars such as Michael Psellos and John Italos in the 11th century and John Tzetzes and Eustathios of Thessalonica in the 12th did not confine themselves to the copying and editing of ancient manuscripts but became the self-appointed exegetes of the Classical tradition, writting essays and commentaries in a broadly "Classical" style, albeit from a Byzantine perspective, and using ancient texts to reflect upon contemporary and often ecclesiastical issues. During the Palaiologan period (13th century on) there was a revival in Classical philology and many Greek texts owe their survival to the efforts of Planudes in the 13th century and Triklinios in the 14th.

Without you narrowing down your inquiry further though it is tough to know what specific areas to hit upon. However, those topics about Socrates, the Suda, and later Byzantine Greek scholarship were the first things to come to mind when I read the OP. Perhaps this will be of some assistance.